# Unsubscribing events from custom ToolTip and custom Flyout class in UWP

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am trying to create my own custom ToolTip class where I register the Loading event in the constructor. How do I unsubscribe from this event? When I do it in the finalizer/destructor, it causes an exception especially when I open a new window of the app and close it:

> COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used.

Here is my code:

```
public class CustomToolTip: ToolTip
{
    public CustomToolTip()
    {
        this.Loading += CustomToolTip_Loading;
    }

    protected void CustomToolTip_Loading(Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement sender, object args)
    {
        // my logic here
    }

    ~CustomToolTip()
    {
        this.Loading -= CustomToolTip_Loading;
    }
}
```

This exception also happens when I create a custom Flyout control and try to unsubscribe the Opening event in the finalizer.

My code:

```
public class CustomFlyout: Flyout
{
    public CustomFlyout()
    {
        this.Opening += CustomFlyout_Opening;
    }

    private void CustomFlyout_Opening(object sender, object e)
    {
        // my logic here
    }

    ~CustomFlyout()
    {
        this.Opening -= CustomFlyout_Opening;
    }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Cleaning up events in the finalizer doesn't make much sense to me as the finalizer won't get called if the object can't be cleaned up due to event references unless i'm missing something. I'd implement IDisposable but alternatively you could probably set the event to null in the Unloaded event instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should not define a finalizer in your class unless you deal directly with unmanaged resources which you certainly don't here.

If you only want to handle the event once regardless of how many times your control is loaded, you could simply unregister the event handler when the `Loading` event has been raised:

```
public class CustomToolTip : ToolTip
{
    public CustomToolTip()
    {
        this.Loading += CustomToolTip_Loading;
    }

    protected void CustomToolTip_Loading(Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement sender, object args)
    {
        this.Loading -= CustomToolTip_Loading;
        //...
    }
}
```

Otherwise, there is an `Unloading` event:

```
private void CustomToolTip_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Loading -= CustomToolTip_Loading;
    this.Unloaded -= CustomToolTip_Unloaded;
}
```

Also note that unregister from an event to avoid memory leaks is only important when the publisher lives longer than the subscriber.

Answer (score 0):

As the T.Schwarz said, it would never get to executing the finalizer if there are still references to the object. Therefore, you need to remove eventHandlers somewhere else, such as the Dispose method.

```
public class CustomToolTip : ToolTip,IDisposable
    {
      ……

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.Loading -= CustomToolTip_Loading;
        }
      
    }
```

Comment: So who is calling `Dispose()`?